# Getting correct section numbering for Appendix in a large document

Tags: numbering, sectioning, appendices

I'm writing a thesis which is an aggregate of separate articles. I have the source code for the articles and I'm using `\include` to include them in the main document of the thesis. So in my main.tex (thesis document), I have

```
\include{article1}
some pages in between the two articles
\include{article2}
```

The problem that I'm getting is with the Appendix sections. In article 1, I have at the end:

```
\appendix
\numberwithin{equation}{section}
\section{Coefficients}\label{sec:Coeffic}
\subsection{Good coefficients}
then comes the first line of appendix
```

This gives in article 1 (when  compiled separately with the article class):

> A. Coefficients
>
> A.1. Good coefficients

and equation numbers in the Appendix A as (A.1), (A.2)

which is ok and what is expected.

When I put article 1 within main.tex, I use `\include` command. Also, I removed the document class for article 1 and put `\chapter` instead.

But when I compile main.tex (the thesis document), I get the appendix sections as:

> .1 Coefficients
>
> .1.1 Good coefficients

and the equation numbers in the appendix A as (.1.1), (.1.2) etc

My article 1 is treated as a chapter in the main thesis document (main.tex) and the title and section numbers, equation numbers are preceded by A in main.tex. This is what I want.

Maybe it would be ok to get the appendix in my main.tex as

> A.A. Coefficients
>
> A.A.1 Good coefficients

and the equation numbers in the Appendix as (A.A.1), (A.A.2) etc

to denote that it refers to appendix A of paper A. First A is for the first article and second A is for first appendix. How to get this?

Comment: What document class are you using?

Comment: Thanks. I'm using book for main.tex . I don't have any class for article 1. I start it with \chapter{title of article}

Comment: I think the problem is that `\appendix` typesets the appendix title with `\section*` so it doesn't get a number. Maybe using `\begin{appendix}` and `\end{appendix} would work? otherwise, you'll have to redfine the section command yourself.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

Preliminary remark: If an article includes an appendix (which is numbered as section A, subsection A.1, ...), and the article as a whole becomes chapter 1 of a book, the appendix in fact becomes a "subappendix" (which should be numbered as section 1.A, subsection 1.A.1, ...).

The `\appendix` command is defined by the document class - basically, it resets the counter of the "top section" level (`\chapter` in book, `\section` in article) and switches to Alphabetic numbering. So an `\appendix` command that is part of an "included" file will produce wrong results - it will redefine chapters instead of sections and in the process interfere with the numbering of subsequent chapters.

Solution: Change the definition of `\appendix` as to produce the desired formatting of "subappendices". (This way, you don't have to change your "included" files.) Keep the redefinition inside a group in order to allow for (main) appendix chapters.

```
\documentclass{book}

\usepackage{amsmath}

\usepackage{filecontents}

\begin{filecontents}{article1}
\section{foo}

Some text.

\appendix
\numberwithin{equation}{section}

\section{Coefficients}

\subsection{Good coefficients}

The first line of the appendix to article1.

\begin{equation}
a^2 + b^2 = c^2
\end{equation}
\end{filecontents}

\begin{document}

\begingroup

\renewcommand{\appendix}{%
  \par
  \setcounter{section}{0}%
  \renewcommand{\thesection}{\thechapter.\Alph{section}}%
}

\chapter{Title of article1}

\input{article1}

\endgroup

\appendix

\chapter{Title of (main) appendix}

Some text.

\end{document}
```

P.S.: I'd rather use `\input` instead of `\include` - you probably don't want a page break after the chapter title.

Comment: Thanks. The problem that I see with your method is that I'll have to include the text of article 1 in main.tex and the latter can become too lengthy if I have several articles. Am I understanding right here that with your method I can't have a separate file article1.tex? Please let me know.

Comment: @yCalleecharan: You CAN have separate files article1.tex, ... - I only used the `filecontents` package (which actually produces the file "article1") in order to produce a working minimal example (which compiles after copying and pasting the code).

Comment: Where did you get that idea? The important part of the solution is *after* the `\begin{document}` in Lockstep's answer. The part before is actually so the answer will compile.

Comment: @lockstep: it seems that `filecontents` will need to be explained, along with `lipsum` and friends when an answer is written...

Comment: @Willie Wong: In the LateX section of the (German-speaking) forum mrunix.de, there`s a topped thread about "error diagnostics" that, among other things, tells you everything about `filecontents` & Co. Perhaps we need something similar for tex.stackexchange.

Comment: Thanks for all your comments. And I've taken a look at the filecontents manual. It was the first time that I encountered filecontents. Yes I can have a separate article 1. And it works like a charm. I prefer to keep the Appendix as A.A.1 and so on...it's just my equations in the first article will be like A.1, A.2 etc...it's slightly better (for me) than having as 1.1, 1.2 etc. Anyway, the problem is solved :).

Comment: I'm using \include. The reason is that I have \chapter{title} in the file article1.tex and not as separate as in your code. 1 vote up.

Comment: Well, I had to guess were you had put `\chapter{title}` - and I guessed wrong. ;-)

Comment: I have a disappearing bibliography issue with this method. Perhaps I'm doing something wrong also. The new post is at: http://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/4462/disappearing-bibliography