# Disappearing bibliography

Tags: bibliographies, subdividing

This is a bit related to my earlier post:

[Getting correct section numbering for Appendix in a large document](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/4451/getting-correct-section-numbering-for-appendix-in-a-large-document)

I'm building a thesis with separate articles. I have a file main.tex and an introduction file intro.tex, and 2 articles article1.tex and article2.tex. I'm showing here below the main.tex with the intro and article 1 only:

```
\begin{document}
some codes for the first few pages
\include{intro}

some code for some intermediate pages

\begingroup

\renewcommand{\appendix}{%
  \par
  \setcounter{section}{0}%
 \renewcommand{\thesection}{\thechapter.\Alph{section}}%
}

\include{article1}

\endgroup
\end{document}
```

In intro.tex, I have at the end:

```
\bibliography{lic}
\bibliographystyle{unsrt}
```

and in article1.tex, I have at the end:

```
\bibliography{mybibs1}
\bibliographystyle{unsrt}
```

The compilation is fine but I see that after article 1 in the pdf file, that the Bibliography lic appears instead of mybibibs1. Intro is followed by Bibliography lic as expected but to my surprise, I get Bibliiography lic also after article 1. And of course I'm getting [?] at every referencing throughout article 1.

What's going wrong here?

Comment: You probably want to look into the `multibib` package. http://www.ctan.org/tex-archive/help/Catalogue/entries/multibib.html

Comment: Thanks but I don't need new names to replace "Bibliography" as the example given on page 4 of the multibib manual.

Comment: I have different bibliography files: 1 for introduction, 1 for article 1, etc..

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I put `\usepackage{chapterbib}` and now it works fine. Any other solutions are welcomed also. Could we do that with multibib also?

I'm accepting my own answer in absence of other answers.