# Remove unnecessary page before bibliography

Tags: page-breaking, double-sided

I'm writing a thesis which is an aggregate of articles. In one article, there's a blank unnecessary page that appears between the final lines of my document and the bibliography when I put it in the thesis. I don't get this behavior when I compiled the article separately with article class. I've tried commands like `\vspace{-10cm}` but to no avail. The extra page is still here. How to get rid of this page?

The thesis is a compilation of articles with each article having its own bibliography. And I'm using `\include` to include each article. Each article has its own `\bibliography` command at the end.

Thanks a lot...

updated information:
I'm using the `chapterbib` package to put the multiple bibliographies. And the documentclass is set as:

```
\documentclass[fleqn,a4paper,twoside,11pt]{book}
```

I don't have openright option. I'm fixing this myself with adding a blank page as necessary.

I'm putting each article as:

```
\begingroup

\renewcommand{\appendix}{%
\par
\setcounter{section}{0}%
\renewcommand{\thesection}{\thechapter.\Alph{section}}%
}

\input{article1}

\endgroup
```

See also this link:
[Getting correct section numbering for Appendix in a large document](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/4451/getting-correct-section-numbering-for-appendix-in-a-large-document)

Comment: What package are you using to get the multiple bibligraphies? By default the bibligraphies are sectioned at the level of the top-order sectioning command of the documentclass, so chapter for books and sections for articles. For book-like classes, the default is to only allow the chapters to begin on the Right-Hand-Side pages. This explains why you are seeing the extra page sometimes, but not in `article`. So please edit the question to include information on the `documentclass` you are using, and how you include multiple bibliographies.

Comment: Does explicitly adding the `openany` option make any difference? Otherwise you should try to produce a minimal but complete example that reproduces the problem and post it here.

Comment: Yes it works fine! Thanks. I thought of this earlier too, tried it, but some reason I removed it. Your comment made me realized that I took it away and forgot to put it back. So yes now Bibliography can appear on either an even or odd page. Thanks a lot.

Comment: I've given you a "great comment" vote

Comment: @Juan A. Navarro: maybe you can put that as an answer so yCalleecharan can accept it?

Comment: Done. solution accepted and 1 vote up.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Try to explicitly give the `openany` option for your document class. My guess is that, even if you didn't specify it, your document class is using a default of `openright`.

Answer (score 2):

Perhaps you need to give the `onepage` option in the documentclass?

Comment: Thanks. I need twopage as the thesis is a book-like document

Comment: Indeed, this doesn't really “solve” the problem, it just changes the style of the document to one where `openright/openany` become meaningless.