# Equation numbers messed up

Tags: equations, numbering

I'm writing a thesis as a collection of different articles. I'm treating each article as a chapter. The first article has Equations numbering A.1, A.2 etc and the second article has equation numbering B.1, B.2 etc. For some unknown reason, now when I compile the thesis, the equations in Article B has numbers as B.2.1, B.2.2 where the middle 2 is the section number. I want to have B.1 and B.2 as before. Why is LaTeX now including the section number in the equation numbering?

Any help would be highly appreciated.

Thanks a lot...

Update: I still have problems after "mpg" answer. The problem is that in my Article 2, the equation numbers are reset at each main section so that I have in Section B.1 equations B.1, B.2 etc and in Section B.2 I get equation numbers B.1 , B.2 again instead of B.3 and B.4. The equation numbers from Article 1 is fine though. I'm attaching a minimal example. Here is the main document (save as main.tex):

```
\documentclass[fleqn,a4paper,openany,twoside,11pt]{book}
\usepackage[latin1]{inputenx}
\usepackage[OT1]{fontenc}
\usepackage{amssymb}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\usepackage{cite}
\usepackage{fancyhdr}
\usepackage{chapterbib}
\parfillskip 0pt plus 0.75\textwidth

\renewcommand\chaptername{Paper}
\renewcommand{\thechapter}{\Alph{chapter}}
\setcounter{secnumdepth}{4}

\pagestyle{empty}
\pagestyle{fancy}
\fancyhead{}
\fancyfoot{}
\fancyhead[LE,RO]{\bfseries{\thepage}}
\renewcommand{\headrulewidth}{0.6pt}
\newcommand{\clearemptydoublepage}{\newpage{\pagestyle{empty}\cleardoublepage}}

\begin{document}

%\clearemptydoublepage
\newpage{\pagestyle{empty}\cleardoublepage\pagenumbering{roman}}
\setcounter{page}{3}

\clearemptydoublepage
\begingroup

 \renewcommand{\appendix}{%
 \par
 \setcounter{section}{0}%
 \renewcommand{\thesection}{\thechapter.\Alph{section}}%
 }

\include{paper1}

\endgroup


\begingroup

  \renewcommand{\appendix}{%
  \par
  \setcounter{section}{0}%
  \renewcommand{\thesection}{\thechapter.\Alph{section}}%
  }

 \include{paper2}
 \endgroup

\end{document}
```

Here is paper 1 (article 1)...save as paper1.tex :

```
\chapter{\huge \bfseries My paper A}

\renewcommand{\chaptermark}[1]{\markboth{#1}{}}
\renewcommand{\sectionmark}[1]{\markright{\thesection\ #1}}
\fancyhead[LO]{\scriptsize \bfseries\rightmark}
\fancyhead[CE]{\scriptsize \bfseries{Paper A}}


\section{Modelling}
\subsection{Simulating}
bla bla bla bla bla blabla blabla blabla blabla blabla blabla blabla blabla bla
bla blabla blabla blabla blabla blabla blabla bla
\begin{equation}\label{eq:eqmotion}
\begin{bmatrix}
m & 0 \\
0 & m
\end{bmatrix}
=
\begin{pmatrix}
F \thinspace \cos \omega_{f} \thinspace t \\
F \thinspace \sin \omega_{f} \thinspace t
\end{pmatrix}
\end{equation}

\section{experiment}
bla bla bla bla bla blabla blabla blabla blabla blabla blabla blabla blabla bla
bla blabla blabla blabla blabla blabla blabla bla
\begin{equation}\label{eq:eqmotion2}
\begin{bmatrix}
m & 0 \\
0 & m
\end{bmatrix}
=
\begin{pmatrix}
F \thinspace \cos \omega_{f} \thinspace t \\
F \thinspace \sin \omega_{f} \thinspace t
\end{pmatrix}
\end{equation}

\appendix
\numberwithin{equation}{section}
\section{force coefficients}
\subsection{second force}
The coefficients of bla bla
\begin{align}
A_{0} & = 15 \nonumber  \\
B_{1} & = 1
\end{align}

\subsection{first force}
\begin{align}
A_{0} & = 14 \nonumber  \\
B_{1} & = 2
\end{align}
```

And paper2 (article 2).......save as paper2.tex :

```
\chapter{\huge \bfseries My paper B}

\renewcommand{\chaptermark}[1]{\markboth{#1}{}}
\renewcommand{\sectionmark}[1]{\markright{\thesection\ #1}}
\fancyhead[LO]{\scriptsize \bfseries\rightmark}
\fancyhead[CE]{\scriptsize \bfseries{Paper B}}

\numberwithin{equation}{chapter}

\section{Modelling}
\subsection{Simulating}
bla bla bla bla bla blabla blabla blabla blabla blabla blabla blabla blabla bla
bla blabla blabla blabla blabla blabla blabla bla
\begin{equation}\label{eq:beqmotion}
\begin{bmatrix}
m & 0 \\
0 & m
\end{bmatrix}
=
\begin{pmatrix}
F \thinspace \cos \omega_{f} \thinspace t \\
F \thinspace \sin \omega_{f} \thinspace t
\end{pmatrix}
\end{equation}

\section{experiment}
bla bla bla bla bla blabla blabla blabla blabla blabla blabla blabla blabla bla
bla blabla blabla blabla blabla blabla blabla bla
\begin{equation}\label{eq:beqmotion2}
\begin{bmatrix}
m & 0 \\
0 & m
\end{bmatrix}
=
\begin{pmatrix}
F \thinspace \cos \omega_{f} \thinspace t \\
F \thinspace \sin \omega_{f} \thinspace t
\end{pmatrix}
\end{equation}

\appendix
\numberwithin{equation}{section}
\section{force coefficients}
\subsection{second force}
The coefficients of bla bla
\begin{align}
A_{0} & = 15 \nonumber  \\
B_{1} & = 1
\end{align}

\subsection{first force}
\begin{align}
A_{0} & = 14 \nonumber  \\
B_{1} & = 2
\end{align}
```

On compiling the main document (with paper1.tex and paper2.tex in the same folder as main.tex), you will note that in paper B (article 2) in section B.2, the equation numbering starts as B.1 again..which is wrong. It should be B.2. What am I doing wrong?

Thanks a lot...

Comment: That's impossible to say unless you give is more information. How do you turn the individual articles into a single document? What document class do you use for your final thesis? If your main file is not too long (hopefully, just a few declaration and \include statements) maybe you could post it here, and we can take it from there. Do you use \renewcommand{\theequation} anywhere?

Comment: Thanks. I'm not using \renewcommand{\theequation} anywhere. I'm using the book class for the thesis. I will try to reproduce the error in a minimal document and post it here.

Comment: You may also look at this post http://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/4451/getting-correct-section-numbering-for-appendix-in-a-large-document on how I'm putting the articles together in a single document.

Comment: Not to be "that guy", but as @Harald suggested, a small working example would be highly appreciated.

Comment: By the way, thanks for providing a working example , but his one is far from minimal.  For example, the fancyhdr stuff is useless here. It is important to remove as many packages as possible since problems are often caused by package interactions. Also, the contents of the equations could be shorter: `1 + 1 = 2` is a nice equation for an example. (Sorry for nitpicking, but as think the ability to make good MWE is essential in *TeX troubleshooting.)

Comment: @mpg : Yes you're indeed right. I'm working against the clock here and I didn't have the time to strip away unnecessary stuff. But yes, in the future I shall provide good MWEs. This will only help the reader to spot the problem. Cheers.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Looks like `\numberwithin` is not meant to be used the way you are trying to use it. (I'm surprised too!) The problem is that it essentially does two things:

1. Calls `\renewcommand*\the<slave counter>{\the<master counter>.\arabic{slave counter}}`
2. Calls `\@addtoreset{<slave counter>}{<master counter>}`

The second one is what change the numbering. Notice that it is "addtoreset". Which means that it will make the increment operation on the master counter trigger a reset of the slave counter. So after calling `\numberwithin{equation}{section}`, the trigger has been laid. And a second call of `\numberwithin{equation}{chapter}` **does not remove the previous trigger**. Therefore the `equation` counter will still be reset everytime the `section` counter increases.

So much for why it does what you see that it does. For a solution, clearly you must stop using the convenient `\numberwithin` command. A substitute is the `\counterwithin` and `\counterwithout` commands provided by the `chngcntr` [package](http://ctan.sqsol.co.uk/help/Catalogue/entries/chngcntr.html).

So you should define, in your preamble, the following commands:

```
\usepackage{chngcntr}

\newcommand*\startappendixeqnumbering{%
    \counterwithout{equation}{chapter}%
    \counterwithin{equation}{section}%
    \renewcommand*\theequation{\thechapter.\thesection.\arabic{equation}}}
\newcommand*\startnormaleqnumbering{%
    \counterwithout{equation}{section}%
    \counterwithin{equation}{chapter}%
    \renewcommand*\theequation{\thechapter.\arabic{equation}}}

\counterwithin{equation}{chapter}  %Set the default
```

And call `\startappendixeqnumbering` before the first appendix and `\startnormaleqnumbering` after the last appendix, before the start of the next chapter.

Comment: (And no, the counterpart to `\@addtoreset` is not defined for the reverse operation. There is, however, a [package that provides](http://www.tex.ac.uk/cgi-bin/texfaq2html?label=running-nos) `\@removefromreset`, which you could use instead.) Also, the redefinition of `\theequation` is not strictly necessary: `\counterwithin` and `\counterwithout` should take care of that. But in case you want numbering schemed different from the default, you know what to do.

Comment: Thanks. First there's a small mistake: \newcommand*\startnormaleqnumbering{$. the $ should be %. Please change it in your answer. The solution works. Now, I got the equation numbering in the appendices as A.A.A.1 in Paper A and B.B.A.1 in Paper B (for the first appendix equation). I had A.A.1 and B.A.1 before. I can modify \renewcommand*\theequation{\thechapter.\thesection.\arabic{equation}}} and take away \thechapter to give me the original numbering. I think this shorter numbering is more reasonable as B.A.1 means Equation 1 in Appendix A of Paper B. What do u think? 1 vote up.

Comment: Ack, of course; sorry about the two mistakes. The `$` sign was just a typo (hit shift 4 instead of shift 5), good that you caught it. The the display of the equation number, I forgot that you may have already `\thesection` to include the chapter number in its display. So yes, in that case you can just use `\thesection.\arabic{equation}`. Else you can also explicitly reference `\Alph{chapter}.\Alph{section}.\arabic{equation}`, but I don't see a need to do that. Cheers.

Comment: Great! both your answer and that of mpg work.

Comment: I'm accepting your answer as it's "more" complete than the one from mpg. Both answers are right and you have both helped me to fix my problem. Wish that I could accept 2 answers!

Answer (score 9):

LaTeX is including the section number because you told it to do so :-) In the cited post, it appears you're using `\numberwithin{equation}{section}`  which precisely means:

- reset equation numbering at each section;
- include the section number in the equation number.

This command is effective for the rest of the document (hence for your second included article). You can switch back to per-chapter numbering by issuing `\numberwithin{equation}{chapter}` just before including this article (again, this will possibly change equation numbering for all future included articles).

**Warning** the above solution doesn't work as advertised unless you add `\@removefromreset{equation}{section}` every time you use `\numberwithin{equation}{chapter}`. The package `remreset` is needed for this. (Precision added after reading the comments by Willie Wong and his answer (which works too).)

**Clarification** You need to make sure `@` is a letter when using `\@removefromreset`, so the complete invocation looks like `\makeatletter\@removefromreset{equation}{section}\makeatother`. (Imported from the comments for the sake of readability.)

Comment: Correct! I use \numberwithin{equation}{section} for the Appendices. So you are right to say that this command carried on to Article 2 as well, hence the trouble. Now, it's fine again. In the minimal example that I was creating to post here, I excluded the appendices and hence the command \numberwithin{equation}{section} that I was issuing...meaning I couldn't reproduce my mistake. Thanks a lot... 1 vote up also.

Comment: By the way, in this case a _good_ minimal (not-)working example would have been enough to identify the problem. As you point out, it's not as easy as it may look. A good way to obtain such an example is the "dichotomy search": at one end, you have a small example not exhibiting the problem, at the other end your complete document. Then you need to either grow the small example until it exhibits the problem or comment things out of your big document until it works, and iterate.

Comment: Thanks. Yes you are indeed right about the "dichotomy search". As the articles are quite long, I lost track that at the end of each article in the appendix section I was using \numberwithin{equation}{section}. And I made the mistake of not including the appendices in my "minimal" example. Hence it was not a good minimal as you pointed out. Thanks for your kind help.

Comment: @mpg,I still have problems and I have taken away that I'm giving you marks for a good answer. U still have my 1 vote up. U have helped me but perhaps there's another problem in my code. I have put a good minimal example this time.

Comment: @yCalleecharan: try following mpg's advice to the letter. Put the `\numberwithin` command *before* the `\chapter` command in the file for chapter 2, not after.

Comment: @Willie Wong: Thanks. I tried that earlier. And it doesn't work. The dirty fix I found is to put \setcounter{equation}{1} before the second equation in paper 2. This works but of course I would like a proper solution and I'm counting on you guys.

Comment: Hum, you are right. I'm going to dig into a bit, but it may be another case where we try to stretch `amsmath` beyond what it is designed for.

Comment: @Willie Wong: you're perfectly right. The funny point is, I even thought at some point that a `\@removefromreset` might be necessary, then I made a test document and after looking to rapidly at the result I thought `\numberwithin` was enough (now I'm wondering why I thought that).

Comment: Edited my answer to add the missing `\@removefromreset` invocation.

Comment: @mpg :Thanks. I try your answer but it doesn't compile. I get the error message: ! You can't use `\spacefactor' in vertical mode. \@->\spacefactor \@m l.11 \@ removefromreset{equation}{section} ? . Can you please indicate where exactly you are putting the \@removefromreset ? I have tried a few places but unfortunately to no avail.

Comment: @yCalleecharan: to use any of the commands with `@` in its name, you need to enclose the command with `\makeatletter` and `\makeatother`. See why here: http://www.tug.org/pipermail/tugindia/2002-January/000178.html

Comment: @Willie Wong : Thanks for this clarification. Now I have \numberwithin{equation}{chapter}
\makeatletter
\@removefromreset{equation}{section}
\makeatother and it works like a charm :).

Comment: @mpg : Maybe you can edit your answer and include the use of \makeatletter and \makeatother as Willie Wong suggested. Thanks.

Comment: @mpg I'm accepting Willie Wong's answer as it's "more" complete that yours. You were the one in the first place to realise what I was doing wrong. Both answers are right though. You have both helped to fix my problem and I am indeed very thankful. Wish that I could accept 2 answers!