# Bind reports/articles into a book, but keep the ability to compile them individually

Tags: sectioning, book-design, input, article

I see a few questions and answers about writing a book/thesis in LaTeX ([here's one](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/8198/combine-several-chapters-separate-files-in-to-one-report)). But I would like to be able to compile reports separately as I write them to have a bunch of standalone documents. Is this possible without a lot of editing each time?

The context: every week for class I have to write a few summaries of the papers we read (some assigned, some just for my own benefit later). So I like the ability to compile each individually each week, then at the end of the semester bind them all into one "book" with pagination and a TOC.

Should I just make standalone articles each week, then edit all manually at the end of the semester into a book? Thanks!

Answer (score 16, accepted):

You could split every report into two files: a main file holding only the preamble and an `\input` as document body, and a second file holding all the actual content.
Then you are able to `\input` or `\include` all the content files in another main file for the book.

```
  % Main file of one report, e.g. `report01.tex`
  \documentclass{report}
  \title{...}
  \begin{document}
  \maketitle
  \input{content01}
  \end{document}
```

The content file then look like:

```
  % content01.tex
  \section{...}
  Some text
```

Book main file:

```
  \documentclass{book}
  % ....
  \begin{document}
  \maketitle
  \input{content01}
  \input{content02}
  \input{content03}
  \input{content04}
  \end{document}
```

This should work fine as long you don't want to keep the report title pages.

There are also packages like `docmute` or `standalone` which allow you to `\include` or `\input` another file which has its own preamble. The preambles of this sub-files are then ignored. 
This is basically the same like above but you don't need to split each report into two files.

Comment: Looking to do something similar, I also ran across the combine and includex packages. The combine packages looks particularly interesting.

Answer (score 0):

I created a project template for the Texlipse IDE which separates the different sections for an article using the exact same principle Martin suggests. I mentioned it in [another post](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/32910/avoid-warnings-in-texlipse/75910#75910). You find it [here](https://github.com/feldob/Texlipse-Article-Template).