# Avoid warnings in TeXlipse

Tags: sectioning, editors, warnings, input, texlipse

I'm using TeXlipse, an Eclipse plugin, to create my TeX documents. To structure my files I use `\input{filename}`. Now the problem is, that every file is one section or subsection. TeXlipse shows me a warning "Subsection has no preceding section" at the beginning of every file in the Eclipse window. How can I avoid this warning? This is not really a problem, because if a file contains only a subsection and is included by `\input{}` into another file, where the section is located, there IS a preceding section. I'd like to avoid this warning to use it for other things like overfull hboxes.

The warning is displayed in Eclipse as shown in the figure:
[image]

Here is a MWE:

**main.tex**

```
\documentclass{scrbook}
\begin{document}
\chapter{Foo}
\section{Foo2}
\input{test}
\end{document}
```

**test.tex**

```
\subsection{Foo3}
```

In the file `test.tex` I get the warning described above.

Comment: Your title mentions "warnings" while your discussion mentions "errors", or "not really an error". Which is it?

Comment: It is always best to compose a [MWE](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/questions/228/ive-just-been-told-i-have-to-write-a-minimal-example-what-is-that) that illustrates the problem including the `\documentclass` so that those trying to help don't have to recreate it.

Comment: @Werner corrected my question...

Comment: Even `\documentclass{article} \begin{document}\subsection{foo}\end{document}` does not produce a warning for me.

Comment: I tried your MWE with TeXLive2011 and did not receive any warnings.

Comment: @PeterGrill Updated my question. Texlipse is an Eclipse plugin...

Comment: I'm confused by 'In the file `test.tex` I get the warning'. Do you mean you try to compile `test.tex`?

Comment: @cmhughes Updated my question. It is not the compile process but the eclipse IDE with the Eclipse plugin Texlipse

Comment: These are called "warning annotations". See [Task and error markers](http://texlipse.sourceforge.net/manual/markers.html#errann): "The plug-in tries to indicate if there are errors in the document. For example,...subsections without a preceding section (or subsubsection without a preceding subsection) cause a warning annotation (the warning annotation is a yellow triangle with a black exclamation mark)." If these annotations are not configurable via some menu option, it may be built in by default. In that case, I would suggest filing a request/bug at http://sourceforge.net/projects/texlipse/.

Answer (score 7):

From the screen shot, it appears as if the warning is displayed when you have a subfile open, not when compiling the main file.  So, looking at this file alone, which is itself not compilable, there is a `\subsection` without a parent `\section`. As I mentioned in the comments, the following:

#### `test.tex`:

```
\documentclass{article}
\begin{document}
\subsection{foo}
    %...other content of this subsection...
\end{document}
```

does *not* result in a warning when compiled. So, perhaps one way of dealing with this is to have a fully compilable sub-file (as shown above) by adding `\documentclass` and `\begin{document}` prior to the content followed by `\end{document}`.  This should eliminate the warning. In the main file, you would need to include [the `standalone` package](http://ctan.org/tex-archive/macros/latex/contrib/standalone):

#### `main.tex`:

```
\documentclass{scrbook}
\usepackage{standalone}
\begin{document}
\chapter{Foo}
\section{Foo2}
\input{test}% import the subsection
\end{document}
```

Martin, the package author provides a [good example here](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/12267/using-subfiles-package-with-sty-files/12268#12268).  Also, do note that the main.tex file will need to include **all** the packages required by the subfiles.

If you include all the packages in the subfiles as well, you will be able to compile each them separately as well.

---

**Update:** However, quoting from the [TeXlipse](http://texlipse.sourceforge.net/manual/markers.html) documentation it appears that this particular issue is hard coded into its own syntax parser:

> The plug-in tries to indicate if there are errors in the document... Also, subsections without a preceding section (or subsubsection without a preceding subsection) cause a warning annotation (the warning annotation is a yellow triangle with a black exclamation mark).

so one way to get around this would be to tell the parser to ignore this portion of your document by surrounding it with `%###` as per [the TeXlipse FAQ](http://texlipse.sourceforge.net/faq.php):

```
%###
\subsection
%###
```

Answer (score 3):

I created a project structure that circumvents this warning. For my articles, I have separate self containing sub-projects for the (sub)sections. It does not require any customized build files or the like, and somewhat enforces a separation of concern (common images, bib, style file ...). You can check it out, it is available [here](https://github.com/feldob/Texlipse-Article-Template).

Answer (score 0):

Here is a solution that doesn't use any workarounds:

- Problems View in Eclipse -> upper-right corner -> "arrow down" button -> Configure contents...
- Types list -> uncheck "Problem".

Leave all others checked. Pdflatex-produced errors will still be displayed.

Comment: This merely removes the "Problem" from the Problems View. You will still see the yellow triangle with the exclamation mark at the left, and the yellow underlining.