# MIKTEX: how to typeset the whole book while working on a chapter?

Tags: miktex, books

When I write a book - I have a master tex file, say book.tex which contains the title, etc., the macros, inputs individual chapter files. When I work on a chapter, say chapter1.tex and see what I did, I have to typeset book.tex. This is inconvenient - Ctrl-t does not do what I want (tries to typeset chapter1.tex), I have to click on another window, etc. Is there is a way around this?

PCTEXv6 can do it but that software is not supported anymore. The files are organized in a project and PCTEX typesets book.tex even if the active window is chapter.tex.

Comment: This is the purpose of `\includeonly`. Just include each chapter with `\include` and `\includeonly` the chapter you are working on. See e.g. https://tex.stackexchange.com/q/87010

Comment: I know about `\includeonly`. The question is about MIKTEX - Ctrl-T tries to typeset the current chapter which is not even a full latex file, it starts with `\chapter{…}`. I need to change the window first to `book.tex`, typeset it, then go back to the `chapter1.tex` window, etc.

Comment: you are asking about keybindings  like control-t in some editor but you have not said what editor you are using! the underlying tex system (miktex in your case) is not relevant here, you are just asking for an editor macro to typeset the required document, so you need to say what editor that is.

Comment: It is TexWorks, which comes standard with MiKTex.

Comment: That depends on your used editor/Ide for writing TeX code. Please see the following question https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/339/latex-editors-ides ...

Comment: Depending on your editor and setup, you might be able to set a master file:
`%!TEX root = yourmasterfile.tex`

Then, whenever I try to compile this subfile, it knows to compile the master file instead. Still compiles everything (and thus can take a while), but no need to change windows anymore.

Answer (score 1):

Oh for the love of God, avoid subfiles. Here's your plan:

First, set up your master file using `\include` (which you indicate in comments that you know how to do):

```
\documentclass{book}
\includeonly{chapter1}
...
\begin{document}
\frontmatter
\include{frontmatter}
\mainmatter
\include{chapter1}
...
\appendix
\include{someappendix}
\include{otherappendix}
\endmatter
\include{endmatter}
\end{document}
```

Then, in your chapter file, you will put at the head of the file:

```
%!TEX root=mybook.tex
```

Most LaTeX IDEs will recognize this comment as an instruction letting them know where the main file is and will then know to run LaTeX on `mybook.tex` and not `chapter1.tex` while you're editing chapter1.

Answer (score 0):

I think I found the answer. Instead of compiling the whole book while working on a chapter, one can do even better - compile the chapter itself. This thread was of help:

[Bind reports/articles into a book, but keep the ability to compile them individually](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/11221/bind-reports-articles-into-a-book-but-keep-the-ability-to-compile-them-individu)

There are several packages which could do this. The package `subfiles` works best for me. References to other chapters or citations do not work but this is not a problem.