# How to include a document into another document?

Tags: include

I have two documents A and B. Both of them are separate documents. But document A also has to include document B.

Now if I use `\include{B}` i get the following error:

```
! LaTeX Error: Can be used only in preamble.

See the LaTeX manual or LaTeX Companion for explanation.
Type  H <return>  for immediate help.
 ...                                              

l.1 \documentclass
                  [11pt]{article}
?
```

So how can I force to include document B with the "style" and "template" of document A?

Comment: Similar questions: http://tex.stackexchange.com/q/11221/2975 and http://tex.stackexchange.com/q/8198/2975.

Comment: if you want document B always to compile with document A as the outside, use 
%!TEX root = docA.tex 
instead of the preamble of document B
http://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/148649/tex-root-to-parent-directory

Answer (score 42, accepted):

Cut the content (the part between `\begin{document}...\end{document}` of `B.tex` into a new file `B-content.tex`.

Change `B.tex` to be:

```
\documentclass{...}
% your preamble here
\begin{document}
\include{B-content}
\end{document}
```

Then put `\include{B-content}` into `A.tex`.

Answer (score 93):

You can use the `standalone`, `docmute` or `subfiles` package to make LaTeX ignore the second preamble.

Simply load the `standalone` package in the main file and `\input` or `\include` the document. This is a good way if the to-be-included documents just holds a picture which should also be compiled standalone. In this case having main files for every picture file would be annoying.

```
% A.tex
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{standalone}
% your preamble here
\begin{document}
% ...
\input{B}% or \include
% ...
\end{document}
```

```
% B.tex (for normal text)
\documentclass{article}
% your preamble here
\begin{document}
% your B content here
\end{document}
```

or if B should hold some diagram only (note the different class):

```
% B.tex
\documentclass{standalone}
% your preamble here
\begin{document}
% your diagram code here
\end{document}
```

Comment: `standalone` looks like a very nice idea.  I'll have to keep it in mind.

Comment: @Matthew: Thanks, I wrote it because I have a lot of TikZ pictures and I hated the long re-compiling runs during the creation of the more complicated ones when they are inside a document. They are used multiple times across my papers, presentations and thesis anyway. Having extra main files for each was to cumbersome for me. Have a look at the options: you can collect all the "sub-preambles" automatically!

Comment: @Martin 1. Is ``B-content`` in your code a typo for ``B``? 2. I am unable to extract your simple examples here from your package documentation. I would recommend clarifying your package documentation accordingly. 3. I cannot specify a path with ``\include``, whereas it works fine with ``\input``. Is that behavior intentional?

Comment: @Sverre: 1. Yes, that was wrong. I corrected it above. 2. I'm planning to rework the manual already. 3. `\include` does a lot more than `\input` and uses the given filename several times for e.g. creating an `.aux` file. Due to security reasons TeX doesn't allow `..` in relative file paths and not absolute file paths at all. I guess one of these two things cause trouble in your case.

Comment: @Martin: What do you mean by ``..``? And "TeX doesn't allow absolute file paths at all"? I use absolute file paths for many things in my preamble.

Comment: @Sverre: Sorry, I forgot to add that this limitations only exists for file *writing*. With `\include` an `.aux` file is written. The `..` means the parent directory, so `../filename` would mean a file one directory down, inside the parent directory.

Comment: when I try to `input` a standalone tex as in https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/215207/looking-to-draw-this-block-diagram-in-tikz an error `can be only used in preamble` occurs

Comment: @Tiina: You need to use `\usepackage{standalone}` in the main document to strip the preamble away.

Answer (score 6):

You can try using the `combine` class but be warned this is not what LaTeX is designed for!

An alternative that I haven't tried is to use the `newclude` package and write

```
\includedoc{fileB.tex}
```

This latter approach assumes that all of the packages, etc., you need are loaded by the first file.

Answer (score 5):

Here is probably a non-conventional way of doing this. I was trying to combine a few files while still hoping to be able to compile each file individually. I used the `catchfilebetweentags` package to get it done.

Let says I have `file1.tex` and `file2.tex`, which I only want to include the part lies between `\begin{document}` and `\end{document}`. I labelled it with tag name of `document`.

In `file1.tex` and `file2.tex`,

```
\begin{document}
%<*document>
    ...
%</document>
\end{document}
```

For clarity, `%<*tagname>` and `%</tagname>` is the way to tag the content to be used in the `catchfilebetweentags` package.

So in my `main.tex`, I want to include the content in `file1.tex` and `file2.tex`.

```
<remember to add preambles that are needed>
\usepackage{catchfilebetweentags}

\begin{document}
    \ExecuteMetaData [file1.tex] {document}
    \ExecuteMetaData [file2.tex] {document}
\end{document}
```

Voila! Here you go! You can still compile each of the file individually.

There is one problem with `cathcfilebetweentags` as mentioned in [\input only part of a file using catchfilebetweentags package](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/40699/input-only-part-of-a-file-using-catchfilebetweentags-package). The line break is not recognised when you are having an empty line to indicate line break.

Thank to [egreg](https://tex.stackexchange.com/users/4427/egreg) for providing the solution [here](https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/40704/31543). Basically you can just add this to your preamble.

```
\makeatletter
\def\CatchFBT@Fin@l#1[#2]{%
   \begingroup
      %\endlinechar\m@ne % <- this is the guilty party
      \makeatletter #2%
      \scantokens\expandafter{%
         \expandafter\CatchFBT@tok\expandafter{\the\CatchFBT@tok}}%
      \CatchFBT@IsAToken{#1}
         {\global#1\expandafter{\the\CatchFBT@tok}}
         {\xdef#1{\the\CatchFBT@tok}}%
      \ifx\CatchFBT@tok#1\else\global\CatchFBT@tok{}\fi
   \endgroup
}% \CatchFBT@Final
\makeatother
```

If you desire more explanation on this, please check out on [\input only part of a file using catchfilebetweentags package](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/40699/input-only-part-of-a-file-using-catchfilebetweentags-package).

Answer (score 4):

As far as I know, include simply inserts the text wherever it is used.  So you can't have a preamble in document B.  At a quick glance, I would create a wrapper document C and use `\include{B}` in both after editing B so that it only contains your desired output text