# catchfilebetweentags package swallows end of line

Tags: line-breaking, input, external-files, catcodes

I would like to include only a part of a `.tex` file into a different `.tex` file. The part I want to include is delimited by some comment tags, as it is used by [catchfilebetweentags](http://www.ctan.org/tex-archive/macros/latex/contrib/catchfilebetweentags/) package.

I tried the solution of [Will Robertson](https://tex.stackexchange.com/users/179/will-robertson) posted in [\input only part of a file](https://tex.stackexchange.com/q/4889/5764) and it worked wonderfully ... except that the space that should appear in the output PDF file when the text jumps from one line to another in the source `.tex` file disappears.

The main file is the following:

```
\documentclass{article}%
\usepackage{catchfilebetweentags}

\begin{document}
\ExecuteMetaData[inputfile]{mytag}
\end{document}
```

while the file where I want the text from (i.e., `inputfile.tex`) is the following:

```
\documentclass{article}%

\begin{document}
Some text.
%<*mytag>
Text to be included in the main file. This is the first line
and this is the second line. See the problem?
%</mytag>

\end{document}
```

In my case, when I proccess the main file I get `lineand` instead of `line and` in the PDF file.

Where is the problem? Is it a catcode problem? I use MiKTeX 2.9 on a Windows 7 machine, if it helps.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

For some reasons the author of `catchfilebetweentags` issues a command

```
\endlinechar=-1
```

that is obviously the cause of this behavior. I don't know if removing it has other side effects, but for your case it seems to work:

```
\usepackage{catchfilebetweentags}

\makeatletter
\def\CatchFBT@Fin@l#1[#2]{%
   \begingroup
      %\endlinechar\m@ne % <- this is the guilty party
      \makeatletter #2%
      \scantokens\expandafter{%
         \expandafter\CatchFBT@tok\expandafter{\the\CatchFBT@tok}}%
      \CatchFBT@IsAToken{#1}
         {\global#1\expandafter{\the\CatchFBT@tok}}
         {\xdef#1{\the\CatchFBT@tok}}%
      \ifx\CatchFBT@tok#1\else\global\CatchFBT@tok{}\fi
   \endgroup
}% \CatchFBT@Final
\makeatother
```

Instead of copying the whole definition from the package, you can use `etoolbox`:

```
\usepackage{etoolbox}
\makeatletter
\patchcmd{\CatchFBT@Fin@l}{\endlinechar\m@ne}{}
  {}{\typeout{Unsuccessful patch!}}
\makeatother
```