# %!TEX root = to parent directory

Tags: compiling, paths

Currently, I am writing a large report. In my previous ones, I always had the chapters and the main file (`thesis.tex`) in the same directory as the individual chapters. This time, however, I created a subfolder called "chapters" and put the chapter `.tex` files in there. But obviously, the command

```
%!TEX root = thesis.tex"`
```

which I previously put at the beginning of each `chapter.tex`, does not work anymore. Since I work on the report from different locations, I can not define an absolute path but need to define a relative one. I tried `%!TEX root = ../thesis.tex` and `/%!TEX root = thesis.tex`, both of which do not work.

I found threads and solutions for `\input` and other commands, none of which solve by problem, though. If anyone was able to shed some light here, I'd be very thankful!

Comment: [Welcome to TeX.SX](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/questions/1436/welcome-to-tex-sx). Note that you don't have to sign with your name since [it automatically appears in the lower right corner](http://tex.stackexchange.com/faq#signatures) of your post.

Answer (score 19):

Try `%!TEX root = ../thesis.tex`

Comment: Thanks, that's actually what I tried to do. Unfortunately, that does not work...

Comment: Try again with a minimal example and directory structure. This should definitely work.

Comment: I get the error message "the file {parent directory}/chapters/../thesis.tex could not be read".

Comment: The path in the error message is correct, though? Have you checked permissions?

Comment: Permission is not a problem, the thing is that tex interprets ../ as a folder called ..

As a result it does not try to access the parent directory but the subfolder .. in the chapters folder.

Answer (score 5):

Although this is an old question, it seems still actual. I stepped over the same problem and

```
../thesis.tex
```

did not do it for me. Since I am using Windows, I tried a backslash instead:

```
..\thesis.tex
```

and guess what - that did it. Hope that helps you Windows users out there ;-)

Answer (score 3):

Not sure if you still need help and maybe my solution is not what you need, but here it goes: The structure in my project basically looks like

```
/.../MScThesis/chapters/partI
```

The `main.tex` (in your case `thesis.tex`) file is in the `MScThesis` folder and the written stuff itself is in a sub-sub-folder.

I use

```
% !TEX root =  ../../main.tex
```

and that works fine. Basically varying the amount of "../" until you reach the right folder above. So in case you have more than just one subfolder, this should do the trick. I have no idea what your chapter-folder looks like so maybe this is a useless answer, but well :)