# Looking to draw this block diagram in Tikz

Tags: tikz-pgf, diagrams

I'm looking to create something like this in Tikz environment. Any tips? help?[image: Block Diagram]

Comment: [Welcome to TeX.SX](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/q/1436). Questions about how to draw specific graphics that just post an image of the desired result are really not reasonable questions to ask on the site. Please post a minimal compilable document showing that you've tried to produce the image and then people will be happy to help you with any specific problems you may have. See [minimal working example (MWE)](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/q/228) for what needs to go into such a document.

Comment: Your question leaves all the effort to our community, even typing the essentials of a TeX document such as `\documentclass{}...\begin{document}` etc. As it is, most of our users will be very reluctant to touch your question, and you are left to the mercy of our procrastination team who are very few in number and very picky about selecting questions. You can improve your question by adding a [minimal working example (MWE)](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/q/228) that more users can copy/paste onto their systems to work on. If no hero takes the challenge we might have to close your question.

Answer (score 10):

Using TikZ, some styles, the `positioning`, `fit` and `calc` libraries. Adjust the settings according to your needs:

[image]

The code (comments included):

```
\documentclass[border=10pt]{standalone}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usetikzlibrary{positioning,fit,calc}

\colorlet{mygreen}{green!80!black}
\colorlet{myblue}{blue!80!black}
\colorlet{myred}{red!80!black}

\begin{document}

\begin{tikzpicture}[
std/.style={
  draw,
  text width=2.5cm,
  align=center,
  font=\strut\sffamily
  },
rnd/.style={
  draw=#1,
  rounded corners=8pt,
  line width=1pt,
  align=center,
  text width=3cm,
  minimum height=2cm,
  font=\strut\sffamily
  },
vac/.style={
  text width=2.5cm,
  align=center,
  font=\strut\sffamily
  },
ar/.style={
  ->,
  >=latex
  },
node distance=0.5cm and 3cm    
]
%The nodes for the left
\node[std] (va)
  {Vehicle Age};
\node[std,below=of va] (fs)
  {Fan Strength};
\node[std,below=of fs] (vs)
  {Vehicle Speed};
\node[std,below=of vs] (cv)
  {Cabin Volume};
\node[std,below= 1cm of cv] (fr)
  {Fraction of Recirculation};
\node[std,below=of fr] (ac)
  {Ambient $CO_{2}$ Concentration};
\node[std,below=of ac] (op)
  {Occupant Parameters};

%The nodes for the center
\node[rnd,right=of va,yshift=-12.5pt] (aer)
  {Air Exchange Rate Determination};
\node[rnd=myblue,below=of aer] (cdm)
  {Carbon Dioxide Built-in Module};
\node[rnd=myred,below=of cdm] (vcm)
  {Vehicle Cabin Module};
\node[rnd=mygreen,below=of vcm] (hvac)
  {\textsc{hvac} Module};

%The nodes for the right
\node[vac,right=1cm of cdm] (occ)
  {Output $CO_{2}$ Concentration};
\node[vac,right=1cm of vcm] (the)
  {Thermal Environment};
\node[vac,right=1cm of hvac] (col)
  {Compressor Load};

%The dashed fitting node
\node[draw,dashed,inner sep=8pt,fit={(va) (cv)}]
  (fit) {};

% Some auxiliary coordinates for the arrows
\coordinate (aux1) at ( $ (va.east|-aer.west)!0.25!(aer.west) $ );
\coordinate (aux2) at ( $ (va.east|-aer.west)!0.50!(aer.west) $ );
\coordinate (aux3) at ( $ (va.east|-aer.west)!0.75!(aer.west) $ );

%The arrows from left to center
\draw[dashed,ar]
  (fit.east|-aer) -- (aer);  
\foreach \Nodo in {fs,vs,cv}
{
  \draw[ar,myred]
    ([yshift=5pt]\Nodo.east) -- ([yshift=5pt]aux3|-\Nodo.east) |- (vcm);  
}
\foreach \Nodo in {fs,vs,fr}
{
  \draw[ar,mygreen]
    ([yshift=-5pt]\Nodo.east) -- ([yshift=-5pt]aux2|-\Nodo.east) |- (hvac);  
}
\foreach \Nodo in {op,ac}
{
  \draw[ar,myblue]
    (\Nodo.east) -- (aux1|-\Nodo.east) |- (cdm);  
}
\draw[ar,myblue]
  ([yshift=5pt]fr.east) -- ([yshift=5pt]aux1|-fr.east) |- (cdm);  
\draw[myblue]
  ([yshift=-5pt]cv.east) -- ([yshift=-5pt]aux1|-cv.east);  

%The arrows from center to right
\foreach \Ori/\Dest in {cdm/occ,vcm/the,hvac/col}
{
  \draw[ar]
    (\Ori.east|-\Dest) -- (\Dest);  
}
\end{tikzpicture}

\end{document}
```

Comment: `\coordinate (aux1) at ( $ (va.east|-aer.west)!0.25!(aer.west) $ );` please explain params after `at`