# Is there any tool to code diagrams from an existing drawing (e. g. png or jpeg)?

Tags: tikz-pgf, diagrams

My intention is to simply code some figure like this:

[image]

Is there any online tool to transform figures or pictures in to latex code?

Comment: I highly doubt it. You can use tools like inkscape and export to TikZ. Other tools export TikZ code directly, but it will be you that is creating the diagram/picture.

Comment: @Johannes_B I support the comment of Johannes - I do not think that this is possible at the moment.

Comment: Well, Inkscape does have the possibility of tracing bitmaps and creating vector paths based on the image, so in theory you could do that and export to TikZ code. However, I would *not* do it for a diagram like that. The text will not be converted to actual text I believe, it will just be a shape like any other, so editing it is hopeless. For diagrams like the one you show you're much better off learning TikZ and  making it yourself I think. There are also various tools for generating code of diagrams, see e.g. http://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/26972

Comment: \includegraphics ;-)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Unfortunately online tool to transform figures or pictures in to LaTeX code not exist. Peraphs with `InftyReader` it is possible. See at the link http://www.inftyreader.org/. But if you want to build your figure, you can use

- `IPE`, http://ipe.otfried.org/;
- `XFig` or `WinFig`, http://winfig.com/;
- `LaTeXdraw`, http://latexdraw.sourceforge.net/
- `InkScape`, https://inkscape.org/en/. With `InkScape` you can create your figure and after you export your picture in `LaTeX`.

Comment: I have read: **Is there any online tool to transform figures or pictures in to latex code?**. My answer is: Online tool to transform figures or pictures in to latex code not exist.

Answer (score 6):

### Short answer:

No, there's not a *one* click tool that gets the PNG and converts it to Ti*k*Z out of the box. But there are routines you can follow to do it. Keep in mind, though, that as [Torbjørn T.](https://tex.stackexchange.com/users/586/torbj%c3%b8rn-t) mentioned, the diagram will *only* have the *advantage* of being a *vector graphic*, there will be **no font consistency**, the generated **code** will likely be **very extense** and perhaps the **converted graphics** will **not** be **so great** after all, therefore perhaps it's better to just convert to PDF and use `\includegraphics`.

For a reference: in [Advices on drawing a complex figure using tikz](https://tex.stackexchange.com/q/340930/81905) there are two ways to convert a PNG: one to SVG and one to Ti*k*Z (the second is done completely in Inkscape). Also take note that SVG can be easily converted to Ti*k*Z.

### Not so long answer:

This I speak from my personal experience on learning Ti*k*Z for the last few months: simple diagrams are worth to draw yourself and learn a bit of the tool after all. By simple I mean with well defined geometric shapes, and with no coloring, shading, shadowing and etc. The reason why I say this are simple:

- **Customization:** if you decide, later on, to use it again but with some changes you can easily do it. If you're not the boss and you're asked to change the picture you can also easily do it. Bottomline you have much flexibility, changing is easy.
- **Difficulty:** it's **not** difficult and there are [plenty of examples](https://tex.stackexchange.com/search?q=%5Btikz-pgf%5D+block+diagram) on the Website to help out. Here's [one that fits nicely to yours](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/215207/looking-to-draw-this-block-diagram-in-tikz), IMHO.
- **All other reasons to learn Ti*k*Z**: [What are the advantages of TikZ/PGF over PSTricks?](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/6676/what-are-the-advantages-of-tikz-pgf-over-pstricks) also some more here [How productive are you with TikZ?](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/52542/how-productive-are-you-with-tikz)
- **TeX.SE:** if you run into some trouble, a specific question here about your issue will *always* be welcome.