# How to make an \input file build on its own?

Tags: input

I am working on an article in LaTeX that I am splitting into multiple files with `\input` commands.  Each section is in one such file of its own.  Is there a way to make these files build on their own while still being able to build the main document that `\input`s them?

Something like this:

```
\if<this is top level>
  \documentclass{article}
  \begin{document}
\fi

Section text goes here

\if<this is top level>
\end{document}
\fi
```

Comment: Maybe [compiling - What are your best practices to compile only a part of the document or presentation (or how do you prepare the big ones)? - TeX - LaTeX Stack Exchange](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/142417/what-are-your-best-practices-to-compile-only-a-part-of-the-document-or-presentat) or [How to include a document into another document? - TeX - LaTeX Stack Exchange](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/11311/how-to-include-a-document-into-another-document?noredirect=1&lq=1)

Comment: @user202729 the `\standalone` package from the 2nd link appears to do what I want.  thanks!