# compile one time for all file pdf/tex and combine to one file

Tags: compiling, texmaker

i use TexMaker 5.0.3

i have 6 file tex (file 1,2...6), and i must compile 6 times of 6 file .tex to create 6 file pdf.
Then in main.tex, i combine 6 file pdf to only one pdf.
Total: 7 times to create main.pdf
My Minimal code in main.tex:

```
\documentclass[a5paper]{article}
\usepackage[a5paper,landscape,left=1.5cm,right=0.3cm,top=1cm,bottom=1cm]{geometry}

\usepackage{pdfpages}
\usepackage{subfiles}
\begin{document}
\includepdf[pages=-]{front_cover.pdf}
\includepdf[pages=-]{./Introduction/Introduction.pdf}
\includepdf[pages=-]{1.pdf}
\includepdf[pages=-]{2.pdf}
\includepdf[pages=-]{3.pdf}
\includepdf[pages=-]{4.pdf}
\includepdf[pages=-]{5.pdf}
\includepdf[pages=-]{6.pdf}
\end{document}
```

With "option: Define current Document = Master Document" : Don't work with command: \includepdf (i don't see any file in structrure view)

How can i compile only one time  to create and combine main.pdf from 6 different file .tex (TexMaker)? 
Thank in advance

Comment: You might be intereste din `\include` or `\input`. For a comparison see here: [When should I use \input vs. \include?](https://tex.stackexchange.com/q/246/134144)  Regarding the 'master document'  you might be interested in: [this answer](https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/94415/134144). Other related questions: [Bind reports/articles into a book, but keep the ability to compile them individually](https://tex.stackexchange.com/q/11221/134144) and [Combine several chapters (separate files) in to one report](https://tex.stackexchange.com/q/8198/134144)

Answer (score 2):

If the 6 subfiles are `.tex`, then there is no need to include them as pdf in that way. All can be compiled in one go from your `main.tex`. This is easiest to explain with an example. Suppose I current have the files for a title page, an abstract and a section of text, with the following directory structure:

```
main.tex
files/
    titlepage.tex
    abstract.tex
    section1.tex
```

If `main.tex` has the contents:

```
\documentclass[a5paper]{article}
\usepackage{lipsum}
\usepackage[a5paper,landscape,left=1.5cm,right=0.3cm,top=1cm,bottom=1cm]{geometry}
\begin{document}
\input{files/titlepage}
\input{files/abstract}
\include{files/section1}
\end{document}
```

Then all three sub files appear in the final document when compiling `main.tex`. The relevant commands are `input{file}`, which inputs the text file into `main.tex`, and `include{file}`, which does the same but introducing a newpage:

[image: output]

Now, this assumes that each of the subfiles are plain 'content' without preambles or `\begin{document}`. For example, my `files/section1.tex' has

```
% !TeX root = ../main.tex
\section{First file}
\lipsum[1][1-5]
```

Note the first line here - this is a special command that tells the compiler that this document is being built from another file (specifically `main.tex`). Depending on your build system, this may not be necessary (but will do no harm either way).

If you would like to retain the ability to compile the subfiles separately, the `standalone` package if for you. This strips the preamble from the subfiles so you can `\input` them without any issues. To use this package, add `\usepackage{standalone}` to your preamble in `main.tex` and use `\documentclass{standalone}` in each subfile (for more information see the [documentation](http://mirrors.ctan.org/macros/latex/contrib/standalone/standalone.pdf)).

Of course, you can combine this workflow with including pdfs in the usual way (e.g. if `front_cover.pdf` was not from a `.tex` file).

Comment: i tried. i used: \documentclass[a5paper]{article}
\usepackage{lipsum}
\usepackage[a5paper,landscape,left=1.5cm,right=0.3cm,top=1cm,bottom=1cm]{geometry}
\begin{document}
\input{files/titlepage}
\input{files/abstract}
\include{files/section1}
\end{document} but many fails: https://imgur.com/SE1oHoF. Please look image